# How do you fix type mismatch in try-catch blocks?

Tags: scala, nullpointerexception, try-catch, typeerror, type-mismatch

I've written a try-catch construct which attempts to read parquet files based on an S3 path (*paths*) obtained from an earlier function. The try-catch construct will change the path if the try block fails and will then try again using the new path:

```
val rawDF: DataFrame = {
      try {
        spark.read.format("parquet").load(paths)
      } catch {
        case NonFatal(e) =>
        Thread.sleep(3600000)
        val hour = LocalDateTime.now().format(hourParser)
        val date = LocalDateTime.now().format(dateParser)
        val paths = f"s3a://twitter-kafka-app/processed-data/date=$date/hour=$hour/*"
        try {
          spark.read.format("parquet").load(paths)
        } catch {
          case NonFatal(e) => None
          print("No path found.")
          }
        }
    }
    rawDF.show()
```

All of these blocks work fine except the final catch block, which causes type mismatch problems because it returns Unit. I've had to specify rawDF as a DataFrame type in order for rawDF.show() to work. I've tried adding 'null' because I was under the assumption that this is how you get around this kind of problem, but it just returns NullPointerException even though I know that the first try block should successfully return the dataframe.

Is there an easy way around this that I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: `rawDF` should be an `Option[DataFrame]` then (and you should return `None` in the last exception). If the rest of the code cannot do anything without this dataframe (e.g this is the entrypoint of the code and the process should crash if it cannot be loaded), then logging and re-throwing (the same exception you caught) is probably the best solution.

Comment: Hadn't seen the `None` before the `print`. This is basically a no-op, since it doesn't do anything and the `print` is the actual return value (since it comes last). You probably want to switch those around. Though your code will still not typecheck, since the type of `rawDF` is `DataFrame` not `Option[DataFrame]`.

Comment: Actually, in Scala,  it’s more convenient to use “Try” rather than Java-ish try-catch blocks. And at the end you will have an instance of Try[Dataframe], then you can convert it to Option or whatever. Like this: Try(spark.read.load(whatever)) orElse Try(spark.read.load(whatever2)). (Sorry about the formatting, I’m on mobile rn :) )

Comment: @Marth Thanks for your help. Literally just read about Options before I saw your comment. My error now is that both try blocks, if successful, would return DataFrame and not Option[DataFrame]. Is there anything I can do here to have them return the latter?

Comment: @parmeni4 _"Is there anything I can do here to have them return the latter?"_ You can return an empty `DataFrame` or read from another source or something, like just think for a second if the read fails how are you going to return a `DF`? how will a `println` magically create a `DF`? You can't. - Or you probably just want to not catch anything at all, and let the program crash since it seems you can't recover from that failure.

Answer (score 1):

Much of this has already been said, but using a `Try` is the better option to get rid of the `try-catch` blocks. Also it signals the operation might fail, but we're not really interesting in what it throws as long as it's non-fatal and we can recover from. `Either` can also be used but it's semantically different.

The only question remains is how will you treat the failure. I would return an empty `DataFrame`. Something like:

```
def tryOfRawDF(paths: String): Try[DataFrame] = Try {
  spark.read.format("parquet").load(paths)
}

val rawDF: DataFrame = tryOfRawDF(paths).getOrElse {
  Thread.sleep(3600000)
  val hour  = LocalDateTime.now().format(hourParser)
  val date  = LocalDateTime.now().format(dateParser)
  val paths = f"s3a://twitter-kafka-app/processed-data/date=$date/hour=$hour/*"
  tryOfRawDF(paths).getOrElse {
    println("No path found.")
    DataFrame.empty
  }
}
rawDF.show()
```